# Facebook like share in android EditText

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink, share

Good day.I want to create an share field like facebook.In the facebook if you insert an link it will automatically get the lets say 'short preview' of your link with an title and image.I dont think that facebook got in touch with whole wordls website databses so it gather them from databases but rather parsing the url somehow.Anyway lets imagine i have an edittext with user letting input some ulr.How can i achieve this kind of technique?By googling i did not find anything closer to what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook downloads the url and displays the title in the header and a few lines of text.  A prominent image on the page if it finds one.  You'd have to do something similar-  download the url, parse the html, and grab enough info to make your preview.

Comment: oh....I see now that is horrible....if so can you give some good practise on how to do it ?by means of code?if you dont mind please?Plus the answer is satisfying enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the websites have og(Open Graph) tags in them. Check out the Facebook Open Graphs Website to understand more  about these tags. You can fetch data corresponding to these tags and that is what most social media sites and WhatsApp do to provide a preview.